# Отправка уведомлений на почту в laravel?

Tags: laravel

Можно ли в laravel настроить отправку уведомлений на почту, таким образом что бы он собирал все записи из таблицы за день и отправлял конкретному пользователю?
Если вручную запустить письмо приходит, а вот по расписанию нет, что не так?
Письмо:

```
   class SendEmail extends Command
{
    
    protected $signature = 'emails:send';

   
    protected $description = 'Command description';

   
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $data = array(
            'name' => "Иванов",
        );

        Mail::send('mail4', $data, function ($message) {


            $message->from('test@test.com', 'И. Иванов');


            $message->to('test@test.com')->subject('Тест письмо');

        });

    }
}
```

И Крон

```
    class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
   
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\SendEmail::class,
    ];
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
      
        $schedule->command('emails:send')->everyTenMinutes();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно.
[Это про то как писать отправителей  почты](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail)

[А это про то, как создавать задания](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling)

[Это про, то как создавать асинхронные jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues)